# Google Play - What happens if I close an open beta?

Tags: android, google-play, playback, beta

When I started distributing my app in Google Play, it was as an opened Beta.

I've recently promote the beta app to production.

The problem is that I have 45k users that have download the app as beta testers, so any review they do is private. I know they can manually get out of the beta, but it's really hard to explain that to them.

So I was thinking of just disabling the beta test, but I'm not sure what is going to happen with all that beta testers.

I couldn't find any documentation about this.

So, if I disable the beta, what is going to happen with them?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? There is no way to "disable beta track" as far as I know.

Comment: I think so too. I've kept the beta users, its handy when I'm trying new features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

I know this is an old thread now but I stumbled upon it today after closing a beta for my app with 100,000 beta users. I simply removed the users and those users were able to stay on that APK until they updated in the play store.